# How to reset display of WYSIWYG editor

Tags: visual-editor, wysiwyg

I recently installed WordPress on a new domain but I have a small problem.  This WYSIWYG editor displays very small text with no padding.  Here are some examples.

**Desired behavior:**

[image: desired behavior]

**Actual behavior:**

[image: actual behavior]

As you can see, the second image shows text which is considerably small and hard to read.  It also has no padding so it runs right into the sides of the text editor.  How can I reset the display?

I'm running WordPress 4.3.1 with the Gravit theme.  No plugins are active.  I installed it yesterday.

Comment: [Enable Debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) ( Debug and Debug log ) and refresh your "Edit Page" page then check and see if there's anything in the debug.log ( /wp-content/ folder ). If nothing shows up use Browser Developer Tools ( F12 ) and check the Javascript console to see if there's errors. If nothing is in *red* or stands out maybe try reinstalling WordPress as something may have been corrupted during the download process.

Comment: If you switch to a default theme, does the problem go away? if yes then contact the support of your theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Theme you are using adds style to the editor using `add_editor_style()`.

Check for that code in theme files and just comment it out by adding a `//` so that it looks like `//add_editor_style( ... );`.

Alternatively, you can look for a file named `editor-style.css` in theme's root directory and rename it to something else.

**EDIT:**
Yes, it does add editor style. You can comment out the line# 326 in functions.php to use the default WordPress styles for Editor.

```
//add_action( 'init', 'gravit_add_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea themes could affect the editor.